# Swift, function types as params with inheritance not compatible

Tags: ios, swift

i am working on a swift framework to implement actionscript 3 event system in swift. There are some limitations such as function pointer comparing is not possible but thats alright. I am at the point of implementing the custom events.

So here is the problem :

https://github.com/philipgeorgiev123/SwiftEvents/blob/master/SwiftEvents/ViewController.swift

i am trying to add custom event listener like :

```
view2.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_TYPE, withFunction: customEventHandler)

func customEventHandler (e : CustomEvent)
{
     var event : CustomEvent = e as CustomEvent
     println(event.customAttribute)
}
```

but the addEventListener line says 'Event' is not subclass of 'CustomEvent'

```
func customEventHandler (e : Event)
{
    var event : CustomEvent = e as CustomEvent
    println(event.customAttribute)
}
```

is there any way to do it without the casting ?

thank you

Comment: What does your `CustomEvent` class look like?

Comment: https://github.com/philipgeorgiev123/SwiftEvents/blob/master/SwiftEvents/CustomEvent.swift